# Ajax creating duplicate forms until page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, duplicates

I have a simple form appear at the bottom of an index page using Ajax to submit the form and reload the index list. For some reason, when cancelling the form or going between pages on the site and opening the form again, duplicates are created. I think the form is being duplicated every time you go to a new page on the site, since cancelling just redirects back to the index page again. I also have the same ajax form setup on a different page that has this same problem.

This is happening in a Rails 4 App using Foundation

index.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Scope Times</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Job</th>
      <th>Scope</th>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Hours</th>
      <th>Completion Rate</th>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <%= render "scope_times/times_list.html.erb" %>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to(new_scope_time_path, id: 'new_scope_time_link', class: 'button tiny radius', remote: true) do %>
  Add New Scope Time Now
<% end %>

<br>
```

_new_scope_time_form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @scope_time, html: { :class => 'form-horizontal' }, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :completion_rate, label: "% Completed", input_html: { :class => "avg"} %>
    <%= f.input :hours, label: "Hours", input_html: { :class => "avg"} %>
    <%= f.input :week, as: :date, label: "Week", input_html: { :class => "avg"} %>
    <%= f.association :scope, collection: Scope.all,:label_method => lambda { |scope| "#{scope.job.name} | #{scope.description}" }, label: "Scope", input_html: { :class => "avg"} %>
    <p>&nbsp</p>
    <div class="form_actions">
        <%= f.submit nil, class: 'button tiny radius' %>
        <%= link_to 'Cancel', scope_times_path, class: 'button tiny radius alert' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

new.js.erb:

```
$('#new_scope_time_link').hide().after('<%= j render("new_scope_time_form") %>');
```

create.js.erb:

```
$('#new_scope_time').remove();
$('#new_scope_time_link').show();
$('#times_list').replaceWith('<%= j render("scope_times/times_list") %>');
```

Refreshing the page fixes the issue even though following a link back to the same page wouldn't. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things keep in mind: -

1) -> Its good practice to use local variables with partial, and also partial name should not contain `.html.erb` while you define `render partila: ''`

assuming `@scopes` contains lists of scopes, and defined in `index` action
its should be

```
<%= render "scope_times/times_list", scopes: @scopes %>
```

2) -> create a partial to _add_new_scope_link.html.erb

```
  <%= link_to(new_scope_time_path, id: 'new_scope_time_link', class: 'button tiny radius', remote: true) do %>
  Add New Scope Time Now
  <% end %>
```

Index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Scope Times</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Job</th>
      <th>Scope</th>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Hours</th>
      <th>Completion Rate</th>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="scope_times_lists">
    <%= render "scope_times/times_list.html.erb" %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<div id="add_new_scope_link">
  <%= render 'add_new_scope_link'%>
</div>

<br>
```

new.js.erb

```
#replace form and remove link
$('#new_scope_time_link').html(<%= j render 'new_scope_time_form' %>);
```

create.js.erb:

```
$('#new_scope_time').remove(); #remove form
$('#scope_times_lists').html("<%= j render 'scope_times/times_list', scopes: @scopes %>"); #refresh scopes lists including new created list
$('#add_new_scope_link').html("<%= j render 'add_new_scope_link'%>"); #add link again to create new form
```

Comment: Thanks for the style tips, the changes you suggested fixed the issue as well but I'm still unsure why the bug was happening with my javascript. Is it something to do with the specific methods I used? Also I defined any @ variables I use in the controllers mostly, in this case in the scope_times' create method, so that should be fine.

Comment: Also something to note is that you apparently can't have <div> elements inside a <table>, so just use the id with the <tbody> tag instead in this case.

Comment: @dylanjack Glad to know that it fixed issue, and thanks for point me out, i have updated answer to use tbody instead of div. :)